# square root of length of vector, squared

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors

I have the following function:

$$ L(w) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ||w - w_t||^2$$

Taking its derivative with respect to w, I get:

$$ \nabla _w L = (w-w_t) \cdot 1$$

(I found this in equation (5) [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~jkeshet/papers/CrammerDeKeShSi06.pdf) (page 5)).

What I'm not sure I understand is why the square root of $||x||^2$ is equal, in this case, to $x$. Shouldn't it be equal to the square root of the dot product of x with x (i.e., ||x||)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Euclidean norm (2-norm) we get
$$
L(w) = 2 \sum_i (w_i - w_{t,i})^2
$$
and the derivative
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j} L 
&= 4 \sum_i (w_i - w_{t,i}) \frac{\partial}{\partial w_j} (w_i - w_{t,i}) \\
&= 4 \sum_i (w_i - w_{t,i}) \, \delta_{ij} \\
&= 4 (w_j - w_{t,j})
\end{align}
so
$$
\text{grad}_w L(w) = 4(w - w_t)
$$
Looking at your citation (page 4, equation 4) suggests you should rather consider
$$
L(w) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_i (w_i - w_{t,i})^2
+ T (1-y_t(w\cdot x_t))
$$
which has the $w$-gradient
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j} L 
&= w - w_t - 
Ty_t \frac{\partial}{\partial w_j}\sum_i w_i x_{t,i} \\
&= w - w_t - 
Ty_t  x_{t,j}
\end{align}
or
$$
\text{grad}_w L = w - w_t - T y_t x_t
$$